# How to count number of even terms which is the sum of consecutive numbers in array. For eg [1,2,2,5,5] , there are 2 pairs whose value result in even

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class even{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1 = scn.nextInt();

    int[] a1 = new int[n1];
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        a1[i] = scn.nextInt();
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        for(int j=1;j>=i+1;j--){
            if((a1[i]+a1[j])%(2)==0){
                count++;
            }
        }        
    }
    System.out.println(count);  
}
```

}

> //Code does not provide the desired output
> For eg [1,2,2,5,5] , there are 2 pairs whose value result in even.
> [2,3,3,1,2] has 2 pairs (3,3 and 3,1). The code is not generating
> desired results

Comment: You need only one loop from 0 to length -1, testing the values of a1[i] and a1[i+1]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test for consecutive numbers you can solve it with one loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] input = {1, 2, 2, 5, 5};
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++){
        if((input[i] + input[i+1]) % 2 == 0) count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

You just have to make sure to only loop til `input.length-1` so you don't get an index out of bounds error.